# Reflection of a plane in a plane.

Tags: geometry, 3d

The question is:

The reflection of the plane $2x+3y+4z-3=0$ in the plane $x-y+z-3=0$ is the plane:

I tried to find the equation of the normal to the plane and then tried putting in some values, but I couldn't do it. I know how to find the reflection of a point about a plane, but I have no idea how to proceed in this one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Start with reflecting the normal of $2x+3y+4z-3=0$ in $x-y+z-3=0$ to get a new normal vector $(a,b,c)$. Write an equation $ax+by+cz+d=0$ for the new plane, and reflect a point of $2x+3y+4z-3=0$ in $x-y+z-3=0$ to get a point $(x,y,z)$. Insert this point into $ax+by+cz+d=0$ to find out $d$.

Comment: I reflected a point on the plane and got a point which lies on the new plane. But I am unable to get the normal vector for the plane via reflection. Could you kindly shed some light on that part?

Answer (score 1):

I propose this strategy ( but I don't know if it's the simpler):

1) find a translation that brings the given planes to parallel planes passing through the origin. This is done taking a point on the straight line common to the two planes.
If I've not made some mistake we can take the translation 
$
T(x,y,z)\rightarrow \left(x,y+\dfrac{15}{7},z-\dfrac{6}{7}\right)
$
and we have the two planes:
$$
a)\qquad 2x+3y+4z=0
$$
$$
b)\qquad x-y+z=0
$$
the first orthogonal to:
$\mathbf{v}=(2,3,4)^T$
and the second orthogonal to:
$\mathbf{u}=(1,-1,1)^T$

2) Now the reflection of $\mathbf{v}$   through the plane $b)$ is given by (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(mathematics)#Reflection_through_a_hyperplane_in_n_dimensions)):
$$
R(\mathbf{v})=\mathbf{v}-2\dfrac{\langle\mathbf{v},\mathbf{u} \rangle}{\langle\mathbf{u},\mathbf{u}\rangle}\mathbf{u}
=(v_1',v_2',v_3')^T
$$
and the reflected plane has equation
$$
v_1'x+v_2'y+v_3'z=0
$$
3) use the inverse translation $T^{-1}(x,y,z)\rightarrow \left(x,y-\dfrac{15}{7},z+\dfrac{6}{7}\right)
$ to find the request plane.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic, easy to understand and straightforward method according to me is this:-

1. Consider any point on the plane that has to be reflected, here $P_1:2x+3y+4z−3=0$. Let $(0,0,\frac 34)$ (or any other of your choice)
2. Now find the reflection of the point in the mirror plane, here $P_2:x−y+z−3=0$.
3. We know that any plane in space is a linear combination of two distinct planes, let the reflected plane is $P_3=P_1 +λP_2$. As the reflection lies in the reflected plane, put the coordinates of the reflected point in $P_3$ and get $λ$, hence $P_3$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vector method for this question.
x-y+z-3=0 is the mirror plane. So equation of normal will be 
i-j+k.
Equation of normal of original plane is 2i+3j+4k.
Now find parallel component of 2i+3j+4k w.r.t. to i-j+k,
Which is equal to {(2i+3j+4k)•(i-j+k)}•(i-j+k)/|i-j+k|^2 = 
i-j+k.
Therefore perpendicular component = 2i+3j+4k-(i-j+k) =
i+4j+3k.
We know perpendicular component will get reversed in direction upon reflection. 
Therefore perpendicular component = -(i+4j+3k)=
-i-4j-3k.
Net reflection vector= perpendicular vector +  parallel vector  = i-j+k +(-i-4j-3k)= -5j-2k.
Now equation of reflected plane is x(α+2) + y(-α+3) + z(α+4) -3-3α=0.
Comparing with this equation we get, 
α+2/0=-α+3/-5=-α+4/-2
Which implies α=-2.
Putting this value  in the equation of plane we get 
5y+2z+3=0

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for formatting advice.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a second method of solving this question.

We know that the reflection of $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$ in the plane $ax+by+cz+d=0$ is given by

$$2(Aa+Bb+Cc)(ax+by+cz+d)=(a^2+b^2+c^2)(Ax+By+Cz+D) \ .$$

In the question, $A=2,B=3,C=4,D=-3$ and $a=1,b=-1,c=1,d=-3$, so using these values we get

$$2(2-3+4)(x-y+z-3)=(1+1+1)(2x+3y+4z-3)$$

which simplifies to $5y+2z+3=0$, which is the required answer.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

A reflection can be written as multiplication with -1 on any component orthogonal to the plane and with 1 on everything that lies in the plane.

So we can split the normal of the plane we want reflected into parts orthogonal and parts which lie in the plane.

This can be done by projection.

$${\bf n_1}\underset{k}{\underbrace{\frac{({\bf n_1}\cdot{\bf n_2})}{(|{\bf n_1}|\cdot|{\bf n_2}|)}}}$$

if $\bf n_1$ and $\bf n_2$ are scaled to have norm 1 then this becomes much easier as denominator will be 1.

This projected part shall be inverted, and the part which is not projected, shall be preserved

$$\underset{preserve} {\underbrace{({\bf n_2} - {\bf n_1} k)}} + -1 \cdot \underset{reflect} {\underbrace{ ({\bf n_1} k)}} = {\bf n_2} -2k\cdot {\bf n_1}$$

Now, we also need to transform one point on the plane. The simplest way is probably to "walk" from origo in the normal direction as long as $-d/|{\bf n_2}|$, if $d$ is the constant term in the plane equation $ax+by+cz+d = 0$.

We can view this as scalar product between vector $\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}x&y&z\end{bmatrix}$ if they are parallel this scalar product shall be 1 times the product of their lengths.

Now this point needs to be reflected. But this you wrote that you already knew how to do.

---

Just to prove that this works here is a sample image of a reflector I implemented for my 3D engine during the last week. The texture is Lake and the back of the cylinder (behind us) is reflected onto it together with a cuboid object a bit further outside.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to reflect $2 x + 3 y + 4 z - 3 = 0 $ in the plane $x - y + z - 3 = 0$.

1. Take the normal vector of the reflecting plane $( x - y + z - 3 = 0 )$, which is $\mathbf{N} = (1, -1, 1) $
2. Normalize $\mathbf{N}$ to get $\mathbf{\mathbf{n}} = \dfrac{\mathbf{N}}{\| \mathbf{N} \|} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} (1, -1, 1) $
3. Compute the reflection matrix $M$

$$ M = I - 2 \mathbf{n n}^T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} - \dfrac{2}{3} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && -1 && 1 \\ -1 && 1 && -1 \\ 1 && -1 && 1 \end{bmatrix} =\dfrac{1}{3} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 2 && -2 \\ 2 && 1 && 2 \\ -2 && 2 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

4. Take a point $\mathbf{P_0}$ on the reflecting plane, for example $\mathbf{P_0} = (3, 0, 0)$, and take a point $\mathbf{Q} = (x,y,z)$ on the plane to be reflected, then the reflection of $\mathbf{Q}$ is $\mathbf{Q'}=(x',y',z')$:

$$ \mathbf{Q'} = \mathbf{P_0} + M (\mathbf{Q} - \mathbf{P_0}) $$

From which it follows that

$ \mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{P_0} + M^{-1} (\mathbf{Q'} - \mathbf{P_0})  = \mathbf{P_0} + M (\mathbf{Q'} - \mathbf{P_0}) \tag{1}$

because $M^{-1} = M $

5. The equation of the plane to be reflected is

$\mathbf{a}^T (\mathbf{Q} - \mathbf{Q_0}) = 0 \tag{2} $

, where $\mathbf{a} = (2, 3, 4) $, and we can take $\mathbf{Q_0} = (0, 1, 0) $

6. Substitute equation $(1)$ in equation $(2)$, you get,

$$\mathbf{a}^T (\mathbf{P_0} +  M (\mathbf{Q'} - \mathbf{P_0}) - \mathbf{Q_0}) = 0 $$

7. Now, $\mathbf{a}^T M = \dfrac{1}{3}( 0 , 15 , 6 ) = (0, 5, 2)$ and $\mathbf{a}^T M \mathbf{P_0} = 0 $, and $\mathbf{a}^T (\mathbf{P_0} - \mathbf{Q_0}) = (2, 3, 4) \cdot (3, -1, 0) = 3$.
8. Therefore, the equation of the reflected plane is

$$ (0, 5, 2) \cdot (x', y', z') + 3 = 0 $$

9. Finally replace $x',y',z'$ with just $x,y,z$ to get

$$ 5 y + 2 z +3= 0 $$

As the equation of the reflected plane.